# Get-Team cmdlet runs but returns no data

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams, csv, powershell-script, cmdlets

I attempting to create a PowerShell script which will return a complete list of Teams in an M365 Tenancy as a csv file. My script appears to run successfully but it does not return the expected data.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -Force -AllowClobber

Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Get-Team | Export-CSV "C:\Users\JohnSLA\Documents\AllTeams.CSV" -NoTypeInformation
```

This returns a csv file with a single column  titled "Length". The column contains about 300 entries, each one is a 3 digit number between 220 and 351. I assume these are the Teams sites but the script is telling me the total length of data in characters instead of showing me the information.

In my second attempt I specified the properties I wanted to be included:

```
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftTeams -Force -AllowClobber

Connect-MicrosoftTeams

Get-Team | Select Title, URL, StorageUsageCurrent, Owner |Export-CSV "C:\Users\JohnSLA\Documents\AllTeams.CSV" -NoTypeInformation
```

This returns a csv file with the desired column headings but no entries. Does anyone have any ideas how I can get a combination of both these results?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use PnP.PowerShell to see if that works. Maybe start with a sample they provide:https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/teams-list-teams-owners-and-members/README.html?tabs=pnpps